# Am I misinterpreting this example of convolution?

Tags: probability, functional-analysis, physics, machine-learning, signal-processing

I am reading the MIT Deep Learning textbook's description of convolutional neural networks and they introduce the mathematical operation of convolution as follows:

> Suppose we are tracking the location of a spaceship with a laser sensor. Our laser sensor provides a single output x(t), the position of the spaceship at time t. Both x and t are real valued, that is, we can get a different reading from the laser sensor at any instant in time. Now suppose that our laser sensor is somewhat noisy. To obtain a less noisy estimate of the spaceship’s position, we would like to average several measurements. Of course, more recent measurements are more relevant, so we will want this to be a weighted average that gives more weight to recent measurements. We can do this with a weighting function w(a), where a is the age of a measurement. If we apply such a weighted average operation at every moment, we obtain a new function s providing a smoothed estimate of the position of the spaceship:
> $$s(t)=\int x(a)w(t-a)da$$

Wouldn't it make way more sense to define the integrand as $x(t-a)w(a)$ in this case, since we want the position function to have some reference of the time value for which we are trying to approximate position? Is this simply a typo in the book, or am I misunderstanding?

Comment: The value would be the same, because x * w = w * x

Comment: Note that CNN usually use a "reverse" convolution with integrand $x(a)w(t+a)$. Then you get the usual convolution in the gradient formula.

Answer (score 1):

The correct way to write the convolution is with a definite integral:
$$s(t)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty x(a)w(t-a)da$$
Now let's do a change of variables, such as $b=t-a$. The limits will switch order and $db=-da$
$$s(t)=\int_{\infty}^{-\infty}x(t-b)w(b)(-db)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}x(t-b)w(b)db$$
As mentioned in the comment, the convolution is commutative.

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out in the comments and the other answer, the result is numerically identical.

However, you are correct that *your* version of the integrand makes more sense, given the textual description in the textbook including the introduction of the variable $a$ as the "age" of the observed data, rather than the time of the observed data.  If we want to weight each observation by its age $a$, then the integrand should consist of the weight associated with that age $w(a)$ and the observation that has age $a$ at time $t$ which is $x(t-a)$.  This gives your version of the integrand $x(t-a)w(a)$

The textbook integral still makes intuitive sense, if you ignore the textual description of the variable $a$ as the "age" of the observation and instead consider it the *time* of the observation.  Then, if we want to weight each observation collected at time $a$ by its age, then the integrand should consist of the observation collected at time $a$ which is $x(a)$ multiplied by the weight associated with its age.  Since its age is $t-a$, its weight is $w(t-a)$.  This gives the textbook version of the integrand $x(a)w(t-a)$.